# Unable to retrieve title of just created window

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to retrieve the title of a window when my hook procedure receive an HCBT_ACTIVATE message.

The problem is that when this message is received for the first time the window seems not to have the caption already set. I think I should maybe add some kind of delay to the call to `GetWindowText`?
(After the window is created and, for example, I receive a HCBT_MOVESIZE or HCBT_DESTROYWND message I can get the correct title)

Answer (score 1):

You should set the hook with [SetWindowHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), using WH_CALLWNDPROCRET to receive the WM_CREATE notification after the message has been processed.

Comment: I see, but actually I read somewhere that the caption should be empty when using HCBT_CREATEWND but not when using HCBT_ACTIVATE, because the second one gets called after the window has been created. Is this wrong? Or is there another way to obtain the same result using CBT hooks?

Comment: Perhaps the title has not been set yet.

Comment: Yeah, the title has not been set, but that's strange because I knew it should've been set after HCBT_CREATEWND.